# How to use adminer with composer autoload.php?

Tags: composer-php, adminer

Earlier I downloaded the adminer from official site and used it like this "site.com/adminer.php", but now i installed the adminer via composer like dependence. How a can get access to adminer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer will fetch Adminer into the vendor folder of your project, e.g. `your_project_folder/vendor/vrana/adminer`.

Keep in mind that you are working with the development version of Adminer, when you fetched it via Composer. That means it's a "multi-file application" and not the "single file version". Actually, there are "multiple-applications" inside this repository, e.g. `editor`, `adminer`.

**Adminer Webinterface**

Inside that folder you will find several other folders, including `/adminer`  and `/editor`, each of them having a `index.php` file.

You might directly start Adminer in your Browser by using the URL to its vendor folder, e.g. http://localhost/your_project_folder/vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php

Same for the Editor, e.g 
http://localhost/your_project_folder/vendor/vrana/adminer/editor/index.php

*Note*: You can't expect that Adminer works as an integrated version of CMS X or Framework Y out-of-the-box. There are plugins or bundles for some systems, e.g. for Laravel: `kohkimakimoto/laravel-adminer`.

**Compiling Adminer**

You may "compile" Adminer into a single file by using the file `compile.php` from the root folder. It accepts arguments for the driver and language.
This replaces relative paths and creates the "single file version" based on the current checkout.

**Autoloading**

Autoloading is only needed, if you want to work on Adminer or use its API (use its classes in your project). Then you might simply include the Composer Autoloader: `/vendor/autoload.php` during the bootstrap of your project.
This step is not needed, if you just want to run Adminers webinterface.

Comment: I'm confused. How can you put .../vendor/.... as a path unless there a routing for it?

Comment: @Scott You run `composer require vrana/adminer`. That will fetch Adminer into the vendor folder. If you have a setup where the PHP files of the application and the vendor folder are not publicly accessible (and only the public folder is), then you would need to define a custom routing - or symlink adminer into the public folder.

Comment: Yeah, I had already pulled it in with composer, I was just wondering if it was plug-able into the routes somehow by creating an inherited or wrapper class or something. I eventually ended up getting it to work but only after a LOT of fixing of the original code require/use/include paths and similar path references. (virtually all of them were set relative to the vendor locations)
I wouldn't recommend it! It was a scary mess but I did eventually get at least the basics of it to work but then gave up when I realized all the sub-functions would need the same treatment.

Comment: (i.e. I didn't want to have to re-write the entire thing - much easier to grab a static version, drop it somewhere in public in an acl secured path and write a view to wrap the code with the custom javascript functionality for sqlite)

Comment: You can't expect that Adminer works as an integrated version of CMS x or Framework y out-of-the-box. But for some systems plugins or bundles exist, e.g. https://packagist.org/packages/kohkimakimoto/laravel-adminer. --- In general it's easier to use the "single file version" of Adminer. But when you fetched the development version via Composer, you can always execute `compile.php`, which replaces paths and creates the "single file version" based on the current checkout.